# Why does ubuntu need reboot after upgrade but centos doesn't?

Tags: server, apt, upgrade, kernel, yum

[Why is server restart required?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741375/why-is-server-restart-required)
[Why is a restart only required on some updates?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36710/why-is-a-restart-only-required-on-some-updates)
[When is it necessary to reboot an Ubuntu system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/672223/when-is-it-necessary-to-reboot-an-ubuntu-system)

After reading these questions, I'm curious about another question: my centos server has never asked me to reboot the system, even if there's a linux-kernel upgrade. It works perfectly for a long time without a reboot.

Why? And is it possible to **safely** run a ubuntu-server for a long time without reboot?

Comment: If you don't reboot you don't get the (kernel) updates activated.

Comment: @SorenA -- the same with core system files. while they can be updated while running, the update does get activated until a restart of the system

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why does ubuntu need reboot after upgrade but centos doesn't?

That is not true.

Ubuntu does not need a reboot after an upgrade/update of a kernel. It is adviced to do so so the new kernel become active but there is no "need" for it.

> And is it possible to safely run a ubuntu-server for a long time without reboot?

Our record for Ubuntu is an uptime of more than 7 years (yes, it ran far longer than the support from Ubuntu lasted).

===

Oh and CentOS also tells you to reboot when there is a change in kernel. See for instance: https://www.redhat.com/archives/rhl-list/2009-July/msg00195.html

> The kernel case is obvious; installing a kernel is useless without a reboot.
>   But in other cases the new stuff will be used together with the old one.
>   For example, replaced libs will be used by programs freshly started, and old
>   libs will be used for programs already running.
>   So, the reboot is not strictly required. maybe you may want to restart
>   some services or applications.